# Show that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x \in \overline{A}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, metric-spaces

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be metric spaces with $A$ a non-empty subset of $X$. If $f$ and $g$ are
>   continuous mappings of $X$ into $Y$ such that $f(a) = g(a)$ for every $a ∈ A$, show
>   that $f(x) = g(x)$ for every $x ∈ \overline{A}$

Because $\overline{A}$ is closed, all sequences in $\overline{A}$ converge to a limit inside the set. Past this I am stumped, what do I need to show to prove this?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is enough to assume that $X$ is a topological space and $Y$ is a Hausdorff topological space. Now, since the interior of the set $A$ is contained in $A$ all we need is to check the behavior of the points from the boundary $\partial A$. Let $b \in \partial A$ and suppose that $f(b) \ne g(b)$. Then, since $Y$ is by assumption Hausdorff, there are two disjoint open neighbourhoods $O_{f(b)}$ and $U_{g(b)}$. Then the set $f^{-1}(O_{f(b)}) \cap g^{-1}(U_{g(b)})$ is an open neighbourhood of the point $b$, disjoint with $A$, in contradiction with the assumption that $b \in \partial A$. Thus, $f(b) = g(b)$ for any point $b \in \partial A$, and consequently also on any point from the closure $\overline{A}$.

Comment: thanks for your answer but I am looking to show it in terms of a metric space

Comment: Well, just add the conventional definition of neighborhoods in the metric space (via open balls), the rest works in more general topological spaces

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \overline{A}$. Then there is a sequence $(x_n)$ in A which converges to $x$. From $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$ for each $n$ and the continuity of $f$ and $g$ we obtain what ?

Comment: that the limits of $f(x_n)$ and $g(x_n)$ are in $A$?

Comment: No. Thats nonsense, since $f(x_n)$ and $g(x_n)$ are in $Y$. We obtain the desired result, that $f(x)=g(x)$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x \in \overline A$. Then $\forall \epsilon \gt 0 \exists a \in A$ with $d(x, a) \lt \epsilon $. Since $f$ and $g$ are continuous we can choose $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, both positive, such that if $d(x, a) \lt \delta_1, d(f(x),f(a)) \lt \frac{\epsilon}2,$ and if $d(x,a) \lt \delta_2, d(g(x), g(a)) \lt \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Let $\delta = $min$\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}.$ Note that $g(a) = f(a)$. Then if $ d(x,a) \lt \delta$, $d(f(x), g(x)) \le d(f(x), f(a)) + d(g(a), g(x)) \lt \frac{\epsilon}2 + \frac{\epsilon}2 = \epsilon$.